# Student coming to office shirtless and unclean

Tags: teaching, etiquette

I am a junior lecturer in first-year maths at a tropical university. At the end of the semester, many students come to my office to ask questions about the subject's materials.

There is one young man in particular who jogs to uni, and arrives at my office shirtless and reeking of sweat. This is somewhat unpleasant for me. I've even taken to leaving a towel over the back of the seat that he uses so that I can replace it after he leaves.

Is there anything I can say to dissuade him from this practice? He appears to be quite oblivious of the discomfort that he causes in others. However, he does not appear to be breaching the [student code of conduct](https://www.jcu.edu.au/policy/student-services/student-conduct-policy).

(for what it's worth, I'm a 28-year-old unmarried female)

Comment: @ff524 Is it really a duplicate? It seems that here the main issue is the smell and the sweat left on furniture, not the inappropriateness.

Comment: @Najib To me, the answers to "students coming to office hours in revealing clothing" apply perfectly to "students coming to office hours all sweaty" "students coming to office hours with heavy perfume" etc. (minus some sexual harassment specifics). It's all under the general umbrella of "students coming to office hours with inappropriate grooming and attire".

Comment: "Somewhat unpleasant": don't worry about it.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. There's a pretty big difference, to me, between "don't criticize the everyday fashion choices of your students" and "politely ask the sweaty smelly shirtless student not to make your office hours part of his exercise routine."

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Comment: as much as we're trying to not see gender differences, there are, otherwise there wouldn't be any genders. The duplicate questions had reverse genders and even with the reversed genders, it is only barely similar. Telling someone that he stinks is completely different from a legal/society point of view, than telling someone that he dresses in a way that arouses you, even though these 2 things might sometimes be the same thing. Conclusion: NOT a duplicate.

Comment: Not a duplicate.